# if then, also with third parameter

Tags: excel, vba

i have a macro running, who check the values in Column 5 and 4.
The Checking should be expand for one more check, if the results of the check from Column 5 and 4 is also positiv, there should be a check if the date value of the Column 6 is also available in the table tbl_Termine.
If this parameter is also positiv, there should be the Value "bei Termin entfernt" in the Cell of Column 7.

```vb
Sub ErgebnisEintragen()
For i = 2 To 13
If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
Cells(i, 7).Value = "entfernt"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

I hope you can understand my Question, and also you can help me!
Thanks a lot
Ö.

i dont know what i have to change, but the code until now is working.

Comment: You can use `Application.Match()` to check if the Col F value is present in the table.  It will return an error if there's no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the short answer i could not post the final code, so there we go,
thanks a lot to taller!

```
Sub ErgebnisEintragen2()
Const TABLE_NAME = "tbl_Termine"
Dim arr, i As Long, c As Range
Set c = Range(TABLE_NAME)
For i = 2 To 13
    If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "entfernt"
    End If
    If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
        If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 6), c, 0)) Then
            Cells(i, 7).Value = "bei Termin entfernt"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest to combine two `If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then` clause into one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ErgebnisEintragen()
    Const TABLE_NAME = "tbl_Termine"
    Dim i As Long, c As Range
    For i = 2 To 13
        If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
            Set c = Range(TABLE_NAME).Find(Cells(i, 6).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then Cells(i, 7).Value = "entfernt"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub ErgebnisEintragen()
    Const TABLE_NAME = "tbl_Termine"
    Dim arr, i As Long, c As Range
    Set c = Range(TABLE_NAME)
    For i = 2 To 13
        If Cells(i, 5).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
            If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 6), c, 0)) Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "entfernt"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```